# Handlebar Default Syntax Is Not Working on My Project but it is working in online Handlebar Viewer Sites

Tags: javascript, html, handlebars.js

I am facing a weird issue on my project. I have a JSON file and using handlebar.js. I am showing some data from JSON file using handlebar HTML syntax. I can able to show all data but for a particular key/value pair or key starting with "/" are not showing. I have checked same Handlebar template syntax and JSON file in "http://tryhandlebarsjs.com/" where it is properly working and showing data (attached screenshot below). Can anyone please check and suggest what I am missing here or there is any alternative solution.

[image]

```
<div class="entry">  <h1>{{test.[/].Name}}</h1>  <h2>{{test.[/test2].Name}}</h2></div>

{"test": {"/": {"Name": "Test 1",}, "/test2": {"Name": "Test 2",}}}
```

Comment: It all looks correct to me. Are you sure the data in the screenshot is what is getting passed to your template?

Comment: yes it is correct.